# Is it possible to link macfuse to a C++ static library?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I have successfully used [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) in the C programming language on OS X 10.6.8 and it works great. 
At some point I need to start making functions calls to a C++ static library (libSomething.a).  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394801/how-do-you-link-a-c-static-library-to-a-c-program?noredirect=1#comment27016377_18394801) people are saying the only way this is possible is modify the c++ source code to make it callable from C (i.e. prepend  extern "C" before function name and return type).  Unfortunately, I do not have access to the source code, just a static C++ library *.a file.

Is there some way I can convert MacFUSE into a C++ or Objective-C program to allow for invoking C++ functions inside a static library?

I would appreciate the C/C++/Objective-C experts in the community to weigh in on this.

I'm using Xcode 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a wrapper, exposing the C++ class as a C-API:

Something.h:

```
class Something {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    Something() { x = 0; }
    void setX(int newX) { x = newX; }
    int getX() const { return x; }
};
```

wrapper.h:

```
#pragma once
typedef void *SOMETHING;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

SOMETHING createSomething();
void destroySomething(SOMETHING something);
void setSomethingX(SOMETHING something, int x);
int getSomethingX(SOMETHING something);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}    // extern "C"
#endif
```

wrapper.cpp:

```
#include <Something.h>
#include "wrapper.h"

SOMETHING createSomething() {
    return static_cast<SOMETHING>(new Something());
}

void destroySomething(SOMETHING something) {
    delete static_cast<Something *>(something);
}

void setSomethingX(SOMETHING something, int x) {
    static_cast<Something *>(something)->setX(x);
}

int getSomethingX(SOMETHING something) {
    return static_cast<Something *>(something)->getX();
}
```